# en-IN locale not working for angular currency pipe

Tags: javascript, angular, currency

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system):

> The Indian numbering system uses separators differently from the international norm. Instead of grouping digits by threes as in the international system, It groups the rightmost three digits together (till the hundreds place) and thereafter groups by sets of two digits. One trillion would thus be written as 10,00,00,00,00,000.

`toLocaleString` function of JavaScript returns in correct format for `en-IN` locale.

```
(123456789).toLocaleString('en-IN', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'INR',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
})  //  ₹ 12,34,56,789.00
```

But Angular's currency pipe doesn't return the same output for `en-IN` locale. Do I need to create custom pipe?

```
{{ 123456789 | currency : 'INR' : 'symbol': '1.2-2' : 'en-IN' }}
<!-- ₹123,456,789.00 -->
```

Comment: which verision of angular are you working with?

Comment: version is Angular 6

Comment: Have you changed angulars locale to en-IN? using registerLocaleData

Comment: @LeonRadley Just came to know about this today. Do I need to do this for every format in case I am intending to make any app global.

Comment: Yes. Only en-US is included as default. But you should only include one at a time. So you need to figure out how you are going to apply localizations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding below lines in `app.module.ts` enabled Indian number format. Also gave example if you want to use multiple locales.

```
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

import localeIn from '@angular/common/locales/en-IN';
registerLocaleData(localeIn);

import localeAr from '@angular/common/locales/ar-EG';
registerLocaleData(localeAr);


<p>
  <!-- ₹ 12,34,56,789.00 -->
  {{ 123456789 | currency : 'INR' : 'symbol': '1.2-2' : 'en-IN' }}
  <br/>
  <!-- ‏د.إ.‏ 123,456,789.00 -->
  {{ 123456789 | currency : 'AED' : 'symbol': '1.2-2' : 'ar-EG' }}
</p>
```

Comment: It can also be set as below : `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
  providers: [{provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-US' }]
});`